# DrawImage above a rectangle j2me

Tags: java, mobile, java-me

I wanted to draw an image above a rectangle that I drew as well but the problem is the image doesn't appear on the rectangle only if I modify the (h/w) so that they don't match with the ones of the rectangle

```
            int x = w / 2 - 20;
            int y = h / 2 - 20;
            g.setColor(255, 255, 255);
            g.fillRect(0, 0, w, h);
            g.setColor(0, 0, 255);
            g.fillRect(0, h / 2, h, w);
            g.drawImage(img, x, y,Graphics.BASELINE);
```

this way the image doesn't appear

---

```
        class GameFish extends Canvas {

        int h = getHeight();
        int w = getWidth();
        int x = w / 2 - 20;
        int y = h / 2 - 20;
        int pas = 10;
        Timer tim= new Timer();
        myTask matache= new myTask();
        Image img;
        public GameFish(){
            tim.schedule(matache, 0,100);
        }

        protected void paint(Graphics g) {
            try {
                img = Image.createImage("/Images/fish1.png");
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
            g.setColor(255, 255, 255);
            g.fillRect(0, 0, w, h);
            g.setColor(0, 0, 255);
            g.drawImage(img, x, y,Graphics.VCENTER|Graphics.HCENTER);

        }

        class myTask extends TimerTask{

        public void run() {
            if(x<0 || x>w-40)
            {
                pas=-pas;
            }
            x+=pas;
            repaint();

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: post full code that may help

Comment: post full running code including import statements if you have more than one class post them.....edit your question to update... Short Self Contained Code Example(SSCCE) is needed